# Why Firebase is unable to recognize logged in user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log in using Firebase Authentication, the login process works.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if(user) {
        console.log('Logged in');
        console.log(user.displayName);
        document.getElementById('userName').textContent = user.displayName;
      } else {
        window.location = '../login';
      }
});
```

The above code works as expected, it logs user display name and the text 'Logged in'.

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
```

This code is present on the same page but surprisingly doesn't works! It logs `null`. This is what the official documentation says to retrieve the currently logged in user

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Now in my case the code doesn't works, always prints `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentUser will be correctly populated after the onAuthStateChanged observer triggers. Until then it will be null. currentUser is synchronous but initial state determination is determined asynchronously.

Comment: this answer should not have been voted down.  It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.currentUser` for that.  `.onAuthStateChanged` is where you want to fire all your UI modifying functions/methods from.  `.onAuthStateChanged` takes a second to initialize, that's why `currentUser` is empty.

BTW, I've built out the auth system boilerplate with all 6 authentication types working.  [It's on Github](https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth).  Demo of it is [here](https://rack.pub/firebase-auth).